# Does english have a name for people who have made a reservation?

Tags: word-request

The title pretty much sums up the problem; if a person make a reservation, is there a word which describes that person as a person who has made a reservation?

Comment: Something like a *reservation holder* or a *confirmed guest*. You could also say *reserver*; people would know what you meant.

Comment: @DanBron Exactly. I'm looking for a single word and wasn't sure if reserver was an accepted word. I tried looking it up but couldn't find it. I think I'll just go with reserver.

Comment: I wouldn't know what *reserver* meant.  Does it mean specifically the person who phoned to make the reservation? Or does it include anyone in the guest party?

Comment: It's very common in English that there is no one word to express an idea, you have to use a phrase. I don't know the context in which you want to use this word, but it's rare for their to be a pressing need to use one word rather than two.

Comment: @Jay I didn't exactly need a single word, but I found it interesting that I couldn't find one "reserving process" is a bit long and clumsy IMHO.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would much prefer "[reservee](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Reservee)" over reserver.

> One to, or for, whom anything is reserved;

The rules aren't standardized, of course, but "reserve" is a French word and we often use the -ee ending in English to [form the past participle](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-ee#English), as with

> employ -> employee
>   train -> trainee

I wouldn't really recognize "reserver" as a word. If you must have a single word for this, I'd use reservee... but I still think that the more common "reservation holder" or similar would be better.

Comment: Neither "reserver" nor "reservee" is a recognized, established word for this idea. In the right context, people could probably guess the intended meaning. Like it two hotel clerks were talking about who had made a reservation and when, and then one of them says,  "Ah, the reserver [or reservee] was Mr Fred Jones", I'm sure the other would know what he meant. But if you just walked up to a friend and said, "Hey, have you ever been a reserver?", I'm sure they'd have no idea what you were talking about.

Comment: Xer generally means someone who does X, while Xee means someone to whom X is done. An "employee" is someone who is employed. An "employer" is someone who employs others. I'd think "reserver" makes more sense here, meaning the person who made the reservation. The reservee would be the room, that's the thing that's being reserved.

Comment: I clearly say (I think) that neither is particularly good.

Comment: Reserver should be the person with whom the reservation is made, not the person making the reservation. The hotel is the reserver and the guest is the reservee.

Comment: I wasn't disagreeing with you, just commenting. :-)

Comment: Oooh, what about reservant?

Comment: I tried looking up reservant but haven't found any traces of it. I'm pretty sure I've seen others use it before.

Comment: @Clearer not sure there is. I'm following the model of register[er]->registrant, attend[er]->attendant, enter[er]->entrant

Answer (score 4):

The industry standard phrase here is "confirmed guest". It's used pretty much universally in restaurants and hotels in the US.

One could create, as Catija has done, the word "reservee", and a native English speaker would know what you meant if they were given the context, but it would not be immediately clear and might get you strange looks and a few chuckles. I also agree with Catija that technically the hotel/restaurant makes the reservation, and the guest is the person for whom the reservation is made, and therefore the hotel/restaurant is the "reserver" and the guest is the "reservee", but the distinction would probably be lost on anyone who doesn't spend their time hanging around grammar forums.

Comment: The word I'm looking for has to be more generic. I was trying to find a word for a process which had reserved a lock in a computer program. "Confirmed guest" doesn't really apply there. I have now found an alternative way of doing things, but I still think it's interesting.